# Groovy Extension being passed null for receiver

Tags: groovy

I have an extension method:

```
static <T> T firstOrNull(List<T> self) {
    return (self == null || self.isEmpty()) ? null : (T) self.first()
}
```

which builds and compiles.   However, when I call it:

```
List<String> list = ["abc"]
assert list.firstOrNull() == "abc"
```

`self` is always null.

I can call the static method directly:

```
CollectionIdioms.firstOrNull(["abc"])
```

which returns the correct result.   Here's my `META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule`:

```
moduleName=Groovy Extensions
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=
staticExtensionClasses=util.CollectionIdioms
```

Comment: What's the groovy version?

Comment: where meta-inf is located? Is it a part of jar? How you are loading jar?

Comment: @dagget it's in a Jar file and used by code with static flags turned on.    groovy version is 2.5.15.   I'll try to put it in a small project later today.  I may stumble on the solution that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your descriptor to look like this, it works:

```
moduleName=Groovy Extensions
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=util.CollectionIdioms
```

You have initialized `staticExtensionClasses` which is for static extensions methods.  You are adding an instance extension method.  The definition of your method in the `CollectionIdioms` class is correctly static, but the extension method being added is actually an instance method.

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/listextension](https://github.com/jeffbrown/listextension).

[app/src/main/groovy/util/CollectionIdioms.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/listextension/blob/d9cc9dc20f14d645dadb903f9dd16c570267e6fb/app/src/main/groovy/util/CollectionIdioms.groovy)

```
package util

class CollectionIdioms {
    static firstOrNull(List self) {
        return (self == null || self.isEmpty()) ? null :  self.first()
    }
}
```

[app/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule](https://github.com/jeffbrown/listextension/blob/d9cc9dc20f14d645dadb903f9dd16c570267e6fb/app/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule)

```
moduleName=Groovy Extensions
moduleVersion=1.0
extensionClasses=util.CollectionIdioms
```

[app/src/main/groovy/listextension/App.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/listextension/blob/d9cc9dc20f14d645dadb903f9dd16c570267e6fb/app/src/main/groovy/listextension/App.groovy)

```
package listextension

class App {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = ["abc"]
        println list.firstOrNull()
    }
}
```

That works:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/listextension.git
Cloning into 'listextension'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 24 (delta 0), reused 24 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (24/24), 60.82 KiB | 1.60 MiB/s, done.
~ $ 
~ $ cd listextension 
listextension (main)$ 
listextension (main)$ ./gradlew run

> Task :app:run
abc

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```